# Correct way to edit data in other orgs as a Connected App?

Tags: rest-api, managed-package, connected-apps

I am currently developing a lightning application that requires some data be synced when the user is not using the application.

To provide an almost real-time experience, I have registered my external server as a connected app and I have it checking for updates within an external db every 10 seconds and pushing data only if there is an update to be pushed.

To push the data to the user's org, I have the first user (who uses my lightning application) in any org proceed with a webserver OAuth process so that I can acquire their access token and push changes to their org (via a RESTResource). As many users from the org can be using the application at the same time, I only use one user's access token to update changes for the entire org so that I don't excessively use API requests.

A problem with this solution is that it has forced me to allot "modify all" permissions to my application's core objects (NOACCESS/READACCESS errors are raised if I don't allot "Modify all" permissions and I try to update everyone's records with one user's access token), and it also requires that someone in the org proceeds with the OAuth flow at least once. 
I am wondering if this is the correct way to deal with data syncing to users' orgs, as it seems to be a security issue..

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of basics we need to understand here:

**[Modify All Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_view_all_mod_all.htm)**: The “View All” and “Modify All” permissions ignore sharing rules and settings, allowing administrators to grant access to records associated with a given object across the organization and it's fine to allot this permission to your custom object.If you will not provide this permission you will not be able to access those records which are not shared with you.

**API User**: The user on behalf of whom you receive access token in web server oauth flow is known as API user generally. In web server oauth flow first time it is required to set this api user so that external application can access the org's data and it is what it is. It requires one time user interaction. The permissions you will provide to this user, only that much access you will get in org.So best practice is to keep the minimum possible permissions assigned to this user.